# WebDriver Chrome problems

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

OS: Windows. Use selenium webdriver. I downloded chromedriver.exe, set path to it, chrome runing but steps not run, this is log:

```
    Started ChromeDriver
    port=26306
    version=14.0.836.0
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    .\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(89): error: Value of: app_launched
      Actual: 1
    Expected: AUTOMATION_SUCCESS
    Which is: 0
    Error while awaiting automation ping from browser process
    .\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(223): error: Value of: automation()->GetBrowserWindowCount(&window_count)
      Actual: false
    Expected: true
    .\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(244): error: Value of: browser_proxy.get()
      Actual: false
    Expected: true
    .\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(269): error: Value of: WaitForBrowserProcessToQuit( TestTimeouts::action_max_timeout_ms(), &exit_code)
      Actual: false
    Expected: true
    .\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(270): error: Value of: exit_code
      Actual: -1
    Expected: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A newer version of chromedriver.exe is probably worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you've tried setting up a proxy?  Do you know if you need to setup a proxy?